# How to get a tweet content using oracle in the smart contract to verify a user

Tags: solidity, oracles, solidity-0.8.x, external-api

I am trying to verify a user using his social media account. For this purpose, I am creating a registration function where a user needs to post his tweet with his existing EOA address.

How can I retrieve the tweet's content within the smart contract? Also, how can I verify if the content is the address of the existing caller? I couldn't find proper chainlink steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new service release by Chainlink 2023 April called [Chainlink functions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/). If you want to oracle node to fetch data from offchain API to onchain smart contract, what you need to do with Chainlink Functions is as below:

1. create a script for your API fetch logic in JS.
2. send the wrapped request to Chainlink functions smart contract.
3. write business logic for returned data in your smart contract.

Please check the sample codes for Chainlink functions [here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit).

Please check the repos for Chainlink functions, the [repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-insurance) for the use case one is to use Chainlink functions to fetch temperature data for decentralized insurance, and the [repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-twilio-spotify) for use case 2 is to use Chainlink functions to fetch data from through Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a high-level outline of the process:

Create a Chainlink oracle to interact with the Twitter API.
Set up a Chainlink job to fetch the tweet content using the Twitter API.
In your smart contract, create a function that requests data from the Chainlink oracle.
When the oracle returns the data, process it within the smart contract to verify the address.